# NULL variables in included files

Tags: php, global-variables

If I have three files "`index.php`" "`file.php`" and "`fns.php`"

*First example (it works):*

**index.php :**

```
<?php
  $var = "Variable Data";
  include "file.php";
?>
```

**file.php:**

```
<?php
  var_dump($var);  #Output will be : string(13) "Variable Data"
?>
```

*Second Example (it don't work) :*

**index.php :**

```
<?php
  include "fns.php";
  $var = "Variable Data";
  load("file.php");
?>
```

**fns.php :**

```
<?php
  function load($file) { include $file; }
?>
```

**file.php**

```
<?php
  var_dump($var); #Output will be : NULL
?>
```

**How to include files using functions like `load()` and keep variables working without additional `Global $var;` ?**

*My Solution :*

```
<?php
  function load($file)
  {
    $argc = func_num_args();
    if($argc>1) for($i=1;$i<$argc;$i++) global ${func_get_arg($i)};

    include $file;
  } 

  #Call :
  load("file.php", "var");
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you include the file inside of the function, the included file's scope is that function's scope.

In order to include additional variables, inject them into the function.

```
function load($file, $var) { include $file; }
```

This way, `$var` will be available.

---

You could even make things more dynamic:

```
function load($file, $args) { extract($args); include($file); }
```

And use it like this:

```
load("path/to/file.php", array("var"=>$var, "otherVar"=>$otherVar));
```

PHP will extract the variables into correct symbol names (`$var`, `$otherVar`).

Comment: +1 for the *right* way, although I suspect the OP will consider this unacceptable because of this clause in the question: `...working without additional Global $var;`. I suspect what he wants is the evil construct of `extract($GLOBALS);`...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to be the best way to do this. I have updated my post with my solution, check it please. Is it a good option?

Comment: @John You solution *might* be a good solution, depending on what you want. If your included file needs to modify the passed arguments so that changes can be seen in the global scope after the file has executed, then yes it is. If all you need to do is read the values of the variables and not affect the global scope with your included script, you would be better to do `${func_get_arg($i)} = $GLOBALS[func_get_arg($i)];` to import a value and not a reference.

Comment: @John Personally I would do `$args = func_get_args(); array_shift($args); foreach ($args as $arg) global $$arg;` because it looks neater, and also with your approach if your global scope contains a variable `$i` or `$argc` it will break your loop. This problem is not present with the `foreach` approach, although with my code if your global scope has a variable called `$arg` something interesting will happen (I'm not actually certain what, let me find out...)

Comment: @John Right, it seems that what will happen is the value of `$var` will be broken in both the function and global scope unless the string `'var'` is the last argument ([see for yourself](http://codepad.org/pK12wK6b)). [Here](http://codepad.org/In7J4fgk) is a demonstration of the problem with your `for` approach. Overall I would say that the answer here is to use the `foreach` and make sure you pass `'arg'` as the *last* argument if it's required. `$args` will not be a problem because of the copy-on-write behaviour of `foreach`.

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks a lot for these useful informations I will rewrite my code.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to include file in function, the scope of variables be in function. If you set variable in function load then it not be `NULL`.

```
function load($file, $var) {
    include($file);
}
```